# Do I need to use documentFragment to insert UL list

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There is a recommendation to use `documentFragment` to insert elements into DOM. Suppose I want to create a `ul` list and insert it into DOM, so I do the following:

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
var li = document.createElement('li');
ul.appendChild(li);
document.body.appendChild(ul);
```

Why would I need to use `documentFragment` here?

Comment: *"There is a recommendation to use `documentFragment`..."* Where? From whom? Under what circumstances? With what supporting information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to, no, you can insert directly into the DOM. Document fragments are useful for building up structures that don't have a single root, and for copy and paste operations, and for off-DOM manipulations, but you don't need one just to append to the DOM.

Comment: thanks, that's what I thougth. here is the bit I don't understand: _and for copy and paste operations, and for off-DOM manipulations_ - can you please provide some simple examples? Is it relevent for elements that have a single root outside the DOM?

Comment: @Maximus: Briefly - Say you're writing a document editor using the DOM. The user selects six separate paragraphs and hits Copy. You need a place to store those six paragraphs. A DocumentFragment is a lightweight place to put them; otherwise, you'd have to create an element they could all be a child of, and then remember to only paste that element's children (not the element itself) later. But when you append a DocumentFragment, it's *automatically* just the children that get appended. For the other, if you want to load some HTML and find something in it, but don't want that in the document.

Comment: Thanks, this one is still not clear: _For the other, if you want to load some HTML and find something in it, but don't want that in the document._ - can you elaborate? And why don't you add the example situation in the answer, I think users will benefit. As it stands, there's not much of usage example of the DocumentFragment on the web

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends. When you just need to insert a bunch of `Node`s once, it's pretty fine to append them directly. In your question, both `ul` and `li` are created and manipulated in memory, and then inserted into DOM. So there's no need to use `DocumentFragment` at all. However, for example, if you need to insert multiple `li`s into a `ul` in DOM based on a collection model, I would recommend you to use `DocumentFragment` to insert `li`s in one shot instead of appending one `li` a time. This is because operating DOM is expensive and using `DocumentFragment` can decrease the manipulation of `DOM` and speed up `DOM`. See difference below.

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4], ul = document.getElementById('#ul')

// solution 1
for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li')
    li.innerText = data[i]
    ul.appendChild(li)
}

// solution 2
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li')
    li.innerText = data[i]
    fragment.appendChild(li)
}
ul.appendChild(fragment)
```

Solution 1 creates `li` in every iteration and append new created `li` into `ul`. So there's 4 time DOM operation in total. Solution 2 just creates `li` and append it into fragment in every iteration. It only operates DOM after the loop to append fragment into `ul`. There's only 1 DOM operation in solution 2. Obviously, solution 2 is a better choice in this example.

Answer (score 0):

The document fragment inherits the methods of Node and implements those of ParentNode interface.

You can simply do this:

```
var fragment = new DocumentFragment();
var a = document.createElement('p');
fragment.appendChild(a);
```